# Connect SQL database with ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to Save data from ASP.NET text field. i want to know how the connection will be like. i have done it with MS Acess database. this is the code.

```
  private static OleDbConnection conn()
    {
        string conn;
        conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sheikh Tariq\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Car\Car.accdb";
        return new OleDbConnection(conn);
    }
    //This is to INSERT data in Car table
    public static void Add(string Manu, string Model, string Register, int Doors, string Colorr, int Upg, int Pri)
    {
        OleDbConnection myadd = conn();
        string query = "INSERT INTO Car( Manufacturer, Model, RegistrationNumber, NumberOfDoors, Color, PossibleUpgrades, Price ) VALUES('" + Manu + "' , '" + Model + "' , '" + Register + "' , '" + Doors + "' , '" + Colorr + "',  '" + Upg + "',  '" + Pri + "')";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myadd);
        try
        {
            myadd.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR", ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            myadd.Close();
        } 
    }
```

this is MS Acess database connection with insert statement. can any one tell how to change it to connect with SQL. and what are the changes.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
DbCommand commandObj = null;
string dataMessage = string.Empty;
IDataAccess dataConn = /*get from web/app.config*/;
try
{
commandObj = dataConn.GetStoredProcCommand("Your insert stored proc name");
dataConn.AddInParameter(commandObj, "@yourParameterName", DbType.Int, 
  your    int value);
commandObj.CommandTimeout = set the value here;
dataConn.ExecuteNonQuery(commandObj);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 /*Print the error message*/
}
finally
{
 commandObj.Connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes you should take in consideration :

1- You should write your connection string in web.config file instead of the .cs file code .

2-You should use [parametersized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of hardcoded SQL to avoid [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

---

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;            
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT into Car (Manufacturer, Model, RegistrationNumber) VALUES (@manufacturer, @model, @registrationNumber)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", manufacturer);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", model);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNumber", registrationNumber);
         //Fill the other param
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            // 
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```